# Series.update() that also uses NA values?

Tags: python, pandas

`some_series.update(other_series)` will overwrite all values on `some_series` with their matching (by index) values from `other_series`. However, it does skip all NA values like None.

What should I use if I want to update `some_series` in place from `other_series`, but also have the NA values apply?

To clarify, this is what I want:

```
In [197]: some_series
Out[197]: 
0    1
1    2
dtype: int64

In [198]: other_series
Out[198]: 
0    None
dtype: object

In [203]: some_series  # after overriding it with other_series:
Out[203]: 
0    None
1       2
dtype: object
```

Comment: Isn't that what `some_series = other_series` will do?

Comment: Are you using update because the span of the index is different for the two series? If not, I would just use some_series = other_series.copy()

Comment: @MarkGraph I don't think the explicit call to `copy()` is necessary here, I tested it and it does create a reference to the other series

Comment: @EdChum: doesn't seem so: `some_series = Series([1, 2]); other_series = Series([None]); some_series = other_series #=> (0   None)`. What I need is `(0   None, 1   2)`.

Comment: I don't understand how you'd expect that kind of result as it looks like you want something like `pd.concat([other_series, some_series], ignore_index=True)` rather than trying to overwrite the lhs

Comment: Where did the zero in your desired concatenation come from?

Comment: @EdChum: sorry for the confusion, check the edited question description for an exact definition of the behavior I expect.

Comment: @MarkGraph: sorry for being unclear, see updated description.

Comment: One way that would work would be `some_series.loc[other_series.index] = other_series`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following would work, this uses `loc` and the other series index to mask the elements we want to overwrite:

```
In [106]:

some_series = pd.Series([1, 2])
other_series = pd.Series([None])
some_series.loc[other_series.index] = other_series
some_series
Out[106]:
0   NaN
1     2
dtype: float64
```

The `loc` is acutally unneccessary in this case

Comment: Thanks!  What do you mean by "The loc is acutally unneccessary in this case"?

Comment: I mean that `some_series[other_series.index] = other_series` would also work

Comment: If `other_series` includes indices outside of `some_series` this is a KeyError! :(

Comment: @AndyHayden true but this is so ill-defined that I've given up polishing this any further, plus I'm watching 30rock and deciding how to waste my vote tomorrow

Comment: @EdChum ha, you call this one ill-defined - (I [raise](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29938321/1240268))! ...not looking forward to waking up to that result. Fingers crossed aye.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is the nicest way, but here's one way. You have to ensure that the Series you want to update includes that of the other (e.g. with reindex).

```
In [11]: s
Out[11]:
0    1
1    2
dtype: int64

In [12]: t
Out[12]:
1   NaN
2     3
3     4
dtype: float64

In [13]: res = s.reindex(s.index.union(t.index))
```

*Note: without this stage, if you just try to update s, you'll get a KeyError.*

```
In [14]: res.loc[t.index] = t

In [25]: res
Out[25]:
0     1
1   NaN
2     3
3     4
dtype: float64
```

---

To update *just* the index of s use the intersection:

```
In [21]: ind = t.index.intersection(s.index)

In [22]: s.loc[ind] = t.loc[ind]

In [23]: s
Out[23]:
0     1
1   NaN
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks, but I actually don't want any labels on `t` that aren't in `s` to be in `res`. In other words, all I want is to override values in `s` with their corresponding (by label) `t` values.

Comment: @DunPeal updated (use intersection rather than union)

Answer (score 0):

```
some_series[other_series.index] = other_series
```